# Запуск virualbox на другом tty терминале Ubuntu

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Есть образ `winxp` для `virtual box`. Необходимо запускать виндовс на другом терминале. Как это сделать? У меня `Ubuntu 12.04`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

запустил на tty8

```
startx /usr/bin/VirtualBox --startvm "winxp" --fullscreen -- :1
```

Где winxp это название виртуальной машины. Команда чувствительна к регистру.

Вах! Не ожидал сам что получится!

Comment: кому помогло проголосуйте, хочу этот ответ отметить как правильный

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Причём тут терминал, если ты через `GUI` запускаешь? Тогда создай новую вируальную  машину и подцепи туда свой образ.

Если же в консоле хочешь в бекграунде  запускать тогда открой любой терминал и запусти средствами `Vbox` (сейчас не помню, какая там команда, но знаю, что можно и без `GUI` запускать)

Comment: возможно я не правильно выражаюсь, перефразирую:в Ubuntu нажимаем ctrl+alt+F6, запускаем некую команду и получаем развёрнутый экран ОС загруженной с образа vbox. Периодически пытаюсь разобраться, но сейчас как то нет времени головой биться об стену :)